# Is there a way to find the linux os name and use it as an argument in an if statement?

Tags: linux, bash, amazon-web-services

I have an issue where I need to install package updates on ec2s, yet I wouldn't know if it is either ubuntu, or RHEL, CentOs, and AmazonLinux2.
the update for ubuntu command is:

```
'sudo apt-get update -y',
'sudo apt-get upgrade -y',
```

while the RHEL, CentOS and AmazonLinux2 update command is:

```
'sudo yum update -y',
```

I want to use command  `cat /etc/os-release` to find out the name then put commands into an if statement to execute the appropriate update command for the OS. However, the output is printed and I have no idea how to take the name argument to use in my if statement. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: does https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6345/how-can-i-get-distribution-name-and-version-number-in-a-simple-shell-script answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
source /etc/os-release
echo "$NAME"
```

Output:

```
Ubuntu
```

or

```
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server
```